# Why would a client not send a FIN?

Tags: networking, tcp, packet

TCP Stream in a tcp dump off a remote network segment showed proper handshake and conversation up to the 8s mark followed by a 20s delay where no packets were sent from either client or server.  Server send sent FIN,ACK followed shortly by client's ACK and then RST packets.  Why wouldn't the client send a FIN?  And is FIN,ACK the proper response for a session timeout from the server's side?

Comment: Can you show the precise conversation ? Perhaps also the capture file ?

Answer (score 0):

The RST means that the client had already closed the connection.

The FIN means that the server closed the connection. It's one reasonable response to a timeout.